# How can I make the F-keys (F1, F2, F3, ...) work differently based on the used keyboard?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, usb

#### Context

I have a MacBook Pro which I regularly "dock" via USB with a DisplayLink monitor. An external USB keyboard is attached to the DisplayLink monitor.

Whenever the laptop is docked I would like to use the USB keyboard with the F-keys acting as standard function keys (F1, F2, F3, etc...) without me having to press an Fn key.

However, when I use the laptop standalone I would like to use the built-in keyboard with the F-keys triggering their special functions (Mission Control, Volume, Brightness, etc...) without me having to press an Fn key.

#### Question

How can I make the functions key behave differently (normal vs special functions) based on the keyboard that is connected?

#### What I've tried

I already use [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) for other tasks and thought it would be a breeze to setup the desired behaviour.
Unfortunately the checkbox which governs the F-key behaviour seems to be global. I tried setting the checkmark for the USB keyboard and off for the built-in keyboard, but it seems the last setting simply prevails, regardless of keyboard device.

[image]

I've also tried [Fluor](https://github.com/Pyroh/Fluor), but that tool uses the active application as the trigger to switch behaviour, not the connected keyboard.

Comment: You could use [**Hammerspoon**](https://www.hammerspoon.org) or [**EventScripts**](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html) to detect changes to **USB** and act accordingly, e.g. using an **AppleScript** _script_ to toggle the **[] Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys** checkbox in e.g.: **System Preferences** > **keyboard**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is easily done in [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/), no script is required to check which USB device is connected.

Instead you can set the function keys behaviour per target device directly.

For the built in keyboard I left the mapping empty, as I want to use the media keys:
[image]

For the external USB keyboard I mapped every F-key to itself:

[image]

The systemwide behaviour of the F-keys is to use them as "special" keys and not as standard keys.

So when I type on the internal keyboard, pressing e.g. <kbd>F10</kbd> is passed onto Karabiner, it simply passes the key through and the Mac mutes the sound.
On the USB keyboard pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> is passed to Karabiner, there it is remapped onto the actual <kbd>F10</kbd> keycode and that is passed on to the the application.